# Buttons to increase/decrease Cookies in PHP [HELP PLS]

Tags: php, cookies

I am trying to have in PHP two buttons. **Button A** to increment (+1) a cookie and **Button B** to decrement to 0 the cookie.

I have this:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['plus'])){


        setcookie( 'cookies', $_COOKIE[ 'cookies' ] + 1, time() + 3600 * 24 );
        $message = 'Number of cookies: '.$_COOKIE[ 'cookies' ];
        echo $message;

}
    if(isset($_POST['delete'])){
    if ( isset( $_COOKIE[ 'cookies' ] ) ) {

        setcookie( 'cookies', $_COOKIE[ 'cookies' ] -$_COOKIE[ 'cookies' ], time() + 3600 * 24 );
        $message = 'Number of cookies: '.$_COOKIE[ 'cookies' ];
        echo $message;
    }
}

?>  
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Cookie</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <form action="" method="post">
   <input type="submit" value="plus" name="plus" />
</form>
<form action="" method="post">
   <input type="submit" value="delete" name="delete" />
</form>

    </body>
</html>
```

I tried to do it but my problem is when i click the first time the A button , it only starts to increase if i click two times. And then if i click to B button, the first time i click increments +1 the A button and the second time i click the B button works fine.

Maybe you can help me, ty and regards!!!

Comment: Also it won't work first time you click because the cookie wont appear in `$_COOKIE` until it is sent, i.e. the next request _after_ you've set it.